# ORMLite join with multiple tables and multiselect

Tags: c#, mysql, ormlite-servicestack

I'm having some issues with selecting the same `model` twice and more times with `ORMLite`.

My query does various `LeftJoin<Model1,Model2>`, and then it does something like this:

```
.LeftJoin<Model2, Model3>((x, y) => x.id1== y.id1, dbConnection.JoinAlias("Alias1")
.LeftJoin<Model2, Model3>((x, y) => x.id2 == y.id2, dbConnection.JoinAlias("Alias2")
.LeftJoin<Model2, Model3>((x, y) => x.id3 == y.id3, dbConnection.JoinAlias("Alias3")
.LeftJoin<Model2, Model3>((x, y) => x.id4 == y.id4, dbConnection.JoinAlias("Alias4"))
```

How can I use `SelectMulti` to get 4 times `Model3`? I mean something like this:

```
db.SelectMulti<Model1,Model2,Model3,Model3,Model3,Model3>(query);
```

I'm sorry if I'm unclear, but I can't post the real code due to NDA.

PS. I'm working with `C#`

**UPDATE**

I've added the following code following @mythz's suggestions (it's the last part of the answer, since I cannot upgrade for now):

```
String customSelection = typeof(Model1).GetModelMetadata().Alias + ".*, 0 EOT," +
                         typeof(Model2).GetModelMetadata().Alias + ".*, 0 EOT," +
                         "Alias1.*, 0 EOT," +
                         "Alias2.*, 0 EOT," +
                         "Alias3.*, 0 EOT," +
                         "Alias4.*, 0 EOT";
```

Then, in my query, I added this:

```
.Select(customSelection);
```

Now I try to get the result with this:

```
dbConnection.Select<Model1, Model2, Model3, Model3, Model3, Model3>(query);
```

This leads to a compile error, which tells me that `IDbConnection` does not contain a definition for `Select` and a `Select` method that accepts a first argument of the type `IDbConnection` was not found. (Compiler tells me that in Italian, I'm rephrasing it).

The error code from the compiler is `CS1061`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wont be able to use the `SelectMulti` API for selecting tables with Join Aliases. There's an [example of selecting from multiple tables](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/#join-aliases) with JOIN aliases in OrmLite's home page:

```
var q = db.From<Sale>()
    .LeftJoin<Contact>((s,c) => s.SellerId == c.Id, db.JoinAlias("seller"))
    .LeftJoin<Contact>((s,c) => s.BuyerId == c.Id, db.JoinAlias("buyer"))
    .Select<Sale, Contact>((s,c) => new {
        s,
        BuyerFirstName = Sql.JoinAlias(c.FirstName, "buyer"),
        BuyerLastName = Sql.JoinAlias(c.LastName, "buyer"),
        SellerFirstName = Sql.JoinAlias(c.FirstName, "seller"),
        SellerLastName = Sql.JoinAlias(c.LastName, "seller"),
    });
```

When finer-grain customization is needed you can [use Custom SQL](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/#typed-sqlexpressions-with-custom-sql-apis) with the [Dynamic ResultSet APIs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/#dynamic-result-sets).

I've just added support for being able to specify a Custom Table Select in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/fd02660ab5561c06cb36fd201b034b645e5bc6b8) which will let you select tables using your custom aliases, e.g:

```
q = db.From<Sale>()
    .LeftJoin<Contact>((s, c) => s.SellerId == c.Id, db.JoinAlias("seller"))
    .LeftJoin<Contact>((s, c) => s.BuyerId == c.Id, db.JoinAlias("buyer"));

var results = db.SelectMulti<Sale, Contact, Contact>(q, 
    new[] { "Sale.*", "buyer.*", "seller.*" })

foreach (var result in results) 
{
    Sale sale = result.Item1;
    Contact buyer = result.Item2;
    Contact seller = result.Item3;
}
```

This change is available from v5.0.3 that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

If you can't upgrade you can achieve the same result by using a Custom Select, e.g:

```
var q = db.From<Sale>()
    .LeftJoin<Contact>((s, c) => s.SellerId == c.Id, db.JoinAlias("seller"))
    .LeftJoin<Contact>((s, c) => s.BuyerId == c.Id, db.JoinAlias("buyer"))
    .Select("Sale.*, 0 EOT, buyer.*, 0 EOT, seller.*, 0 EOT");

var results = db.Select<Tuple<Sale, ContactIssue, ContactIssue>>(q);
```

Comment: I'm still not able to make it work... I've edited the original question attaching my attempt to follow your last suggestion. Thank you for the patience

Comment: @magicleon copy my code carefully, you either need to use .Select<Tuple<T,T2>> or upgrade to v5.0.3 to use the new SelectMulti. Refer to the working integration test in the commit I linked to if you get stuck. If you still have an issue create a dummy example that shows the issue.

Comment: If I put Tuple it tells me that "Non generic Tuple type cannot be used with type arguments"

Comment: @magicleon Of course Tuple<T> allows typed arguments. The integration test shows a working example, please follow it exactly. If you’re getting a compile error you’re doing it wrong.

Comment: Allright it seems to work. The only problem is that I have too many elements in my tuple and I have to use TRest, which I belive is not supported, am I right?

Comment: @magicleon I don’t know what you mean by TRest, but my answer contains the available solutions.

Comment: Perfect, I'll need a thorough study of that. By the way, the OP issue is solved, thanks.